# jQuery: Possible to use object and serialize for passing parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
    $.post('/ur.l'
          , jQuery('selectors').serialize() 
                               + '&textareaname=" + escape( $("#textarea").val() )
          , function(data) { ... } 
          }
    );

    $.post('/ur.l'
          , {'foo':'bar', 'foobar','qazbar'}
          , function(data) { ... }
    );
```

---

#### Problems

1. Is it possible to combine the object into `{...}` the jQuery serialization?
2. jQuery doesn't seem to serialize textareas, is there a better method than the above?
   I've tried and see that the textarea is in the jQuery object, but the text is blank:

   ```
   jQuery('input, textarea').serialize()
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) will serialize an object into a url encoded string. You can then combine them together.
2. `serialize` *does* works with textareas. Make sure you have a valid name on the textarea, and that it is not disabled.

Comment: yes, I think my code uses `param`, however I'm almost definite the textarea was not being serialized.  I tested in firebug and it showed that the textarea was properly found by the selector, but that it was not being serialized.  I first tried a lot of text, then I used only a few words, neither worked.  I'll check more next week.

Comment: Yeah I tested it here (http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/PGtPa/) and it seems to work, but it definitely wasn't working at the office... we'll see.

Comment: It still wasn't working, but I'll accept this regardless, I'll have to debug and see what's up.  It may be a browser problem.

Comment: Josiah - "...and that it is not disabled" that's what bit me.

Comment: for example `<textarea name="TextArea1" disabled></textarea>` the disabled attributes informs the `serialize` function to ignore this element. Disabled html form elements are not submitted with a natural form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and give your form an id and refer to the form parameters through that. For example if you form was had an id of #form.

```
$("#form").submit( function () {    
    $.post(
   'ur.l',
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){

    });
    return false;   
  });   
});
```

and $(this) will be the contents of all of your form parameters. Also in case you are not doing so already, take a look at the headers.

Comment: I did try that initially and realized that my textarea wasn't being serialized.  Though, there are many thing in the form that I did not want being sent.